# How can validate multiple form In one page using form token to prevent CSRF Attacks?

Tags: php

Well, In my website I am using PHP unique form token to prevent CSRF attacks. The unique form token and form token validation function is bellow :

```
// generate new token for every form
function generate_Form_Token($form_name) {        
    $token = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));                  
    $_SESSION[$form_name.'_token'] = $token; 
    return $token;
}

// validate form request
function verifyForm ($form, $url){
    // call the form processing page
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";   
    if($actual_link !== SITE_URL."$url") 
        return false;    
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest')
        return false;      
    if(!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token']))
        return false;
    if(!isset($_POST['_token']))
        return false;
    if($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['_token'])
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now If I have one form in one page then it's validating the form successfully.

**BUT** in my website I have a page called `create-menu.php` Here I am using 4 form So this 4 form will generate 4 unique form token and I am use following input field to every 4 form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo generate_Form_Token('menu_creation'); ?>">
```

But the problem is when I validating the form (Using Ajax) in `process.php` page. In this page only 1st form is validating but other 3 form is showing me error message (my custom error message if the form token is not match with session).

**process.php page**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(verifyForm('menu_creation','menu-creation')) {
    // my code.....
    }
}
```

How can I solved this type of issue ? Can anyone assist me with that ? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function that generates the token **once**. Store the return value in a variable. Use that variable in each form.

Comment: I am using same technique in the Admin panel and there are page to create Location. So, Normally admin user will open multiple page to add Multiple Location quickly. But admin can't open the multiple page. It's showing error. Is there any idea about it ?

Comment: Running multiple pages in parallel will cause the same race condition. In that case you need to generate a token for a session instead of a page view. (Or have a time based one with some storage of historical tokens so they can continue to be used for X minutes after a new token is generated by a different page load)